# Organizing two elements in template

Tags: jquery, menu

The website is: http://example3.flenj.server306.com/
The CSS template I'm working with is here: http://example3.flenj.server306.com/styles/styles.css

I have a menu (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm) that I have added to a website template that I installed onto my server.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to manipulate the menu so that it will always be in the center of the browser window? Right now, it's set with a margin in CSS and it's staying put ... I'd like it to move if a browser window is made smaller or larger...
2. What coding do I need to use to make sure that the menu doesn't fall behind the scroll images, but in front of it?

This neophyte needs help. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to your first question is to set it's margin to **auto**, [reference](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html).
On your second question you should use z-index css property, [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Theodore! I just wanted to stop by and say that -- in general - we try not to use W3Schools as a reference, for several reasons. Please try and use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS). Take care, bud! *side note -- #1 for the correct answer.*

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that.
I am sorry for my mistake, as a web standards fan I would be glad to give me a reference about that reasons, for educational reasons 
Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Unfortunately, those did not work ... the auto margin positioned it to the left ... and I copied it exactly as it was written in the reference. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: As I can see in your code you are raw coding an image for background 
`<center><img src="images/menu.png"></center>`.
This one "pushes" your menu down, try to cat this node and give your menu a background in your css.